# PhpStorm Map Absolute Paths

Tags: phpstorm

No matter what I try, I can't seem to get PhpStorm to recognize my absolute pathing:

[image: PHP Storm Error]

Things I've tried:

- PHP Include Path
- "Sources" folder type
- Deployment Server

I've tried everything I could think of and researched

I basically need something to say:

`/local/path = /var/www`

Comment: Why exactly you want to make IDE recognise that path? Just to get rid of the warning?

Comment: **2)** Am I correct in my understanding of your setup: you run PhpStorm on your computer but require path is actually remote one? **3)** Why not have such file in your actual project and assemble absolute path during runtime (e.g. `__DIR__ . '/relative/path/to/file'`) ?

Comment: @LazyOne, yes. Also, to use ctrl+click in order to open files directly.

Comment: How "PHP Include path" will help you here if you are trying to use absolute path? Especially if path is remote one but not local. Deployment settings do not participate in file paths resolving when coding -- IDE works with project files only. That's why I strongly suggest doing something like I have described in #3 -- if done properly will work in IDE locally as well as during actual execution on remote server.

Comment: As for actual warning -- you may suppress it for that statement only (Alt+Enter while caret on problematic place; in appeared menu choose right option and press "Arrow Right" key (or click on small triangle on the right side); then choose "Suppress for statement"). https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/suppressing-inspections.html?search=suppress